# Use id generated with input statement in a subsequent query with knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I have this `knex` insert:

```
knex('notes')
  .insert({
    user_id: userId,
    customer_id: customerId,
    product_id: productId,
    note: text,
  })
```

It adds a record to a `notes` table which has an `id` column.

I'd like to use the `id` from the row that gets created here in my next statement which is:

```
const response = await knexnest(knex('notes')
  .select([
    'notes.id AS _id',
    'notes.note AS _note',
    'notes.user_id AS _userId',
    'notes.customer_id AS _customerId',
    'notes.product_id AS _productId',
    'notes.timestamp AS _timestamp',
    'tags.id AS _tags__id',
    'tags.title AS _tags__tagTitle',
    'tags.type AS _tags__tagType',
  ])
  .where('notes.id', noteId)
  .innerJoin('note_tags', 'notes.id', 'note_tags.note_id')
  .innerJoin('tags', 'note_tags.tag_id', 'tags.id'));

  return response;
```

How can I do this? I know the insert has a `.return()`. I think I could potentially return the `id` to my original call, then have a second call to run the select but that seems overly complicated.

Comment: https://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning
Yes I think you will need to use this.
`const { id: noteId } = await knex('notes').returning('id').insert({/**/})`

Comment: "The allowed contents of a RETURNING clause are the same as a SELECT command's output list (see Section 7.3). It can contain column names of the command's target table, or value expressions using those columns. A common shorthand is RETURNING *, which selects all columns of the target table in order."

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I think there is no shorter solution.

You cannot use complete queries in RETURNING clause.

```
const { id } = await knex('notes')
  .returning('id')
  .insert({
    user_id: userId,
    customer_id: customerId,
    product_id: productId,
    note: text,
  })

return knexnest(knex('notes')
  .select([
    'notes.id AS _id',
    'notes.note AS _note',
    'notes.user_id AS _userId',
    'notes.customer_id AS _customerId',
    'notes.product_id AS _productId',
    'notes.timestamp AS _timestamp',
    'tags.id AS _tags__id',
    'tags.title AS _tags__tagTitle',
    'tags.type AS _tags__tagType',
  ])
  .where('notes.id', id)
  .innerJoin('note_tags', 'notes.id', 'note_tags.note_id')
  .innerJoin('tags', 'note_tags.tag_id', 'tags.id'))
```